# Horizontal scroll event not firing on windows

Tags: javascript, html

Let's keep this really simple. I have two divs.

```
<div class="element-1">

    <div class="element-2"> 

    </div>

</div>
```

`element-2's` width is greater than `element-1's` width. Therefore, I have set `overflow:scroll` on `element-1`.

I have also attached an event listener on `element-1`. This fires on a scroll event.

```
$('.element-1').on('scroll', (event) => {
    console.log('im scrolling');
})
```

Now on my mac, using chrome, this works as expected. However, on windows, using chrome, the event never gets fired.

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/ivan_bacher/pen/gOYvJYB)

---

UPDATE:

So i noticed that if you press the shift key on windows. The scrolling event fires.

```js
$('.element-1').on('scroll', (event) => {
 console.log('im scrolling');
})
```

```css
.element-1 {
 background-color: blue;
 width: 600px;
 height: 200px;
  
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 
 overflow: scroll;
}

.element-2 {
 width: 1200px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element-1">
 
 <div class="element-2"> 
 
 </div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: AFAIK this is the normal behavior. The scroll will only scroll vertically on Windows, unless you hold the shift key

Comment: Please include all relevant code here on Stack Overflow in addition to any external sites. Note that you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do much of what CodePen does, here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Right now your codePen is working in my chrome on windows.

Comment: Try adding overflow-y:scroll as well?

Comment: It is working without the Shift key also in my chrome on windows.

Comment: Only works with the shift key for me. Chrome Version 76 on Windows

Answer (score 2):

The default scroll direction on Windows is *vertical*. If you want to scroll *horizontally* instead, use `Shift` + `Arrow Key` or `Shift` + `Mouse Scroll Wheel` or the horizontal scroll bar at the bottom.

Comment: Is there anyway to disable this and make the event fire without pressing shift?

Comment: You can have a look into your system controls whether the default scroll direction could be inverted. But I don't know if that's possible. With JavaScript you could create a listener on scroll events, use `event.preventDefault()` and send a fake scroll event in the opposite direction. However, that would be very cumbersome...